# Committing Django private keys in portfolios is a problem?

Tags: django, github

I new at Django and created an e-commerce website just for portfolio purpose(I will not use it for sell anything real, at most i going to host it in some domain to show as a portfolio) and committed it in a public Github repository, then Github sent me an email telling me i committed the secret keys of Django, is there any problem with this? Do i need to delete the repository and generate another Secret Key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be sufficient to make sure that the committed key is not used in production by exchanging the deployed key. You don't need to delete the whole repository if you want to delete a single file and remove it from the version history. You can use this guide here to do so: https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository
Following some best practices (e.g., https://12factor.net/) you should not have the secret key directly inside your `settings.py` but rather use an environment variable for this.